# DevExpress XtraGrid dynamically change column width when using CustomDrawCell

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using `CustomDrawCell` event to draw editors and borders manually. Depending on the content of the cells, I want to change the width of the corresponding column. However, I realized that changing the width of the column has no effect. I have checked all the flags related to auto sizing, etc.

How can I override the column width calculation and draw?

Comment: Is OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth property of gridview set to false?

Comment: @muludag: Yes. It it.

Comment: Please clarify where you set the GridColumn.Width property.

Comment: @Svetlana: Inside `CustomDrawCell` event

Comment: Have you tried simply invoking the [GridColumn.BestFit method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.BestFit.method) within the event handler?

Comment: I think, you should try it somewhere after loading data instead of CustomDrawCell event.The problem doesn't occurs when columns widths set separately after loading the data.

Comment: I think this is impossible to solve without you showing us the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the column width after you bind the data.